# arcpy.da UpdateCursor where_clause

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, cursor

I am trying to get a where_clause working on a UpdateCursor (arcpy.da). I can get it to work fine with a SearchCursor, but for some reason the same clause throws a RuntimeError: General function failure error.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace = "C:/mydata/mylocation/Results"
fc = "airports.shp"
delimfield = arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(fc, "STATE")
queryString = delimfield + " <> 'AK'"
cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc,["STATE"], queryString)
for row in cursor:
    print row
    row[0]="AK"
    cursor.updateRow(row)    
del row
del cursor
```

Comment: Try making your workspace defined to the results directory and the fc just the airports.shp.

Comment: That didn't seem to do the trick.  But, I did discover if I move my airports into a geodatabase it seems to work.  I wonder if this is a bug of some kind...

Comment: have you already solved it?

Answer (score 1):

You may have the feature class or raster currently open in ArcMap.

I had this issue (same ambiguous error as I began the for loop) when trying to update a GRID VAT, and it worked after I closed my ArcMap session.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few things to be mindful of when using update cursor and env workspace related to your  question:

1. Setup up workspace to data parent directory (e.g. either to results dir or .gdb)
2. If using env workspace to define fc variable as either 1. for shp, `fc = 'airport.shp'` or 2. as .gdb fc reference, `fc = 'airports'`
3. Use same field names between the query variable and cursor reference (here you are using two different fields STATE and NAME)

Comment: I updated my script, but still am getting this error:          RuntimeError: General function failure error

Comment: Are you receiving a line number where it is failing at?

Comment: Hi. Yes it is the line that starts the for loop: for row in cursor: